# SQL Select Statement with WHERE, AND, OR

Tags: mysql, select, operators, where-clause

I would like to perform a `SELECT` query with MySQL. My goal is to select all the dogs in a vet database that would be `sex=male` and `fur=short` and (`color=black or size=big`)

Note: I want to select dogs that are either black or size is big. They don't have to fulfill the 2 requirements. They just need to fulfill either one.

I have written the SQL statement below but I'm not not sure if I'm right:

```
SELECT name, sex, fur, color 
FROM dogs 
WHERE TRUE sex='male' AND fur='short' AND color='black' OR size="big";
```

Pardon my phrasing if it's too confusing.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

According to [**Operator precedence for MySQL**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/operator-precedence.html) `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`.

So 
`C1 AND C2 OR C3` will be treated as `(C1 AND C2) OR C3`

To override the default precedence you need to use parenthesis as:`C1 AND (C2 OR C3)`

In your case the right query is:

```
SELECT name, sex, fur, color 
FROM dogs 
WHERE sex='male' AND fur='short' AND (color='black' OR size="big");
```

Comment: Thnaks codaddict. Should there be an 'AND' between 'WHERE TRUE' and "sex='name'"?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to add parentheses, so the OR condition gets evaluated correctly.

```
SELECT name, sex, fur, color 
FROM dogs 
WHERE sex='male' AND fur='short' AND (color='black' OR size='big');
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you use parentheses in the description of your goal is correct. The syntax is:

```
SELECT name, sex, fur, color 
    FROM dogs 
    WHERE sex="male" AND fur="short" AND (color="black" OR size="big");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this and its working;

```
SELECT name, sex, fur, color 
FROM dogs 
WHERE sex="male" AND fur="short" AND (color="black" || size="big");
```

Answer (score 0):

select name, sex, fur,color from dogs where sex ='male' and fur = 'short' and (color ='black' or size ='big');